# helpp, i have a problem with google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have a problem, i want to use the camera and make a face recognition but idk how to conect both, the proyect is in google colab and i use javescript to use the camera

i want that the camera and the face recognition work

## start streaming video from webcam

cap = video_stream() #this inizialice the webcam

```
# label for video
label_html = ' Lector de rostros'
# initialze bounding box to empty
bbox = ''
count = 0

    
while True:
    js_reply = video_frame(label_html, bbox)


    face_locations, face_names = sfr.detect_known_faces(js_reply)
    for face_loc, name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
        y1, x2, y2, x1 = face_loc[0], face_loc[1], face_loc[2], face_loc[3]

        cv2.putText(frame, name,(x1, y1 - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 200), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 200), 4)


if not js_reply:
        break
```